# Why is present simple used here?

Tags: grammar, tenses, present-perfect, present-tense

We had a sentence in an exam, and we were asked to choose the right tense of the verb, the sentence goes as follows

> They are having dinner; they (*haven't had, don't have*) any problems at all.

Now the answer was (don't have) but I couldn't understand why, shouldn't it be in perfect tense, if it was to imply that no problems happened?

Comment: Neither option is right or wrong (unless the context made it clear which one was appropriate). "They haven't had any problems" - nothing happened earlier to make them late for dinner. "They don't have any problems" - there is nothing wrong now.

Comment: Thanks, I really suffer from these sentences, no context is made clear yet they appear in exams

Comment: Also, the example sentence could be called a 'comma splice' -- two sentences joined with a comma without a conjunction -- which is not great writing.

Comment: @Khaled Oqad, Just as User8356 said, your example is incorrect. You can fix the error by changing the comma to a semicolon or by inserting a conjunction instead of the comma.

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't pay attention to that